# How can i raise a message error when introducing the same company and username

Tags: python, django

Hi guys I'm creating a django form I'm introducing companies and users to create a license, I would like that you cannot register the same user with the same company

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    """User form model."""          
    company = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=models.CompanyInfo.objects.all(),
        empty_label=None,
        error_messages={"required": "Please enter customer company."},
    )
    user_name = forms.CharField(
        error_messages={"required": "Please enter username."},
        empty_label=None,
    )
    full_name = forms.CharField(
        error_messages={"required": "Please enter customer full name."}
    )
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
```

I would like to create the validaton here, I've been trying to use "unique" direct to de field in the form but i noticed i cannot use it, how can i create that kind of validation directly in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to go with simple `forms.Form`, you need to add clean method that will search model for user_name and company. If your model is named `UserLicence`:

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
"""User form model."""          
company = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=models.CompanyInfo.objects.all(),
    empty_label=None,
    error_messages={"required": "Please enter customer company."},
)
user_name = forms.CharField(
    error_messages={"required": "Please enter username."},
    empty_label=None,
)
full_name = forms.CharField(
    error_messages={"required": "Please enter customer full name."}
)
email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

def clean(self):
    super().clean()
    cc_company = self.cleaned_data.get('company')
    cc_user_name = self.cleaned_data.get('user_name')
    if UserLicence.objects.filter(company=cc_company, user_name=cc_username).exists():
        raise ValidationError('This user name is already registred with this company')
```

But if you would go with `forms.ModelForm` you simply go with `UniqueConstraint.fields` in model:

```
class UserLicence(models.Model):
    #your fields
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['company', 'user_name'], name='unique_user_company')
            ]
```

The `ModelForm` will validate it for you:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = UserLicence
       fields = '__all__'
```

The constraint is desirable anyway no matter if you use modelform or just form

Comment: The code is giving me an error "UserLicense matching query does not exist"

Comment: Oh it should be .filter instead of .get I will update my answer